# How to prevent opening child sub menu in nested menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to prevent opening nested child categories when you open sub categori

for example i have nested tree like this

Test 1

Sub cat 1/1

```
Sub Sub cat 1/1
```

Sub cat 1/2

Test 2

Sub cat 2/1

Sub cat 2/2

When i click Test 1 is opening all nested categories how to prevent opening Sub Sub cat 1/1 ?

PS. system wont let me post question because is mostly code , but i dont see reason to spam random text when i can examplain question in 2-3 lines

```js
$('ul li').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.menu-wrapper ul', this).toggleClass('menu-close')

        $(this).toggleClass('menu-open')

    })
```

```css
ul{
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
  }

  ul li{
    padding: 5px 0;
  }

  ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .menu-close{
    display: none;
  }


  /* Main menu */
  .menu-main{
    width: 250px;
  }
  .menu-main li{
    position: relative;
  }

    .has-menu:before{
      content: '+';
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }

    .has-menu.menu-open:before{
      content: '-' !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-main">
      <li class="has-menu">
        Test 1
        
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
          
          <ul class="menu-child menu-close">
            <li class="has-menu">
              <a href="">Sub cat 1/1</a>
              <div class="menu-wrapper">
                <ul class="menu-subchild menu-close">
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Sub Sub cat 1/1</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
          <ul class="menu-child menu-close">
            <li class="">
              <a href="">Sub cat 1/2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
        
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$("li").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children("div").children("ul").toggleClass("menu-close");

  $(this).toggleClass("menu-open");
});
```

```css
ul{
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
  }

  ul li{
    padding: 5px 0;
  }

  ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .menu-close{
    display: none; 
   /*background-color:red;*/
  }

  /* Main menu */
  .menu-main{
    width: 250px;
  }
  .menu-main li{
    position: relative;
  }

    .has-menu:before{
      content: '+';
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }

    .has-menu.menu-open:before{
      content: '-' !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-main">
  <li class="has-menu">
    Test 1
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
      <ul class="menu-child menu-close">
        <li class="has-menu">
          <a href="">Sub cat 1/1</a>
          <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <ul class="menu-subchild menu-close">
              <li>
                <a href="">Sub Sub cat 1/1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="menu-child menu-close">
        <li class="">
          <a href="">Sub cat 1/2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the child-selector:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('> .menu-wrapper > ul', this).toggleClass('menu-close');
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

(Updated)

Comment: this is not working sub sub cat 1/1 is still opening

Comment: Okay, got it.. so try this https://codepen.io/thomas-frobieter/pen/LYyyprN

Comment: HI, you can also use So code snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet